# How to sort an array of items by an Observable attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I have an Observable of Objects array of the same class = Observable<[MyClass]>. MyClass contains an Observable attribute sortAttribute = Observable. 
I want to sort my array depending on the observable sort attribute.

```swift
class MyClass {

    let title:String
    let sortAttribute:Observable<Int>

    init(withTitle title:String, andSortValue sortValue: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.sortAttribute = Observable.just(sortValue)
    }

}

let arrayToSort:Observable<[MyClass]> = Observable.just([
    MyClass(withTitle: "A", andSortValue: 4),
    MyClass(withTitle: "B", andSortValue: 2),
    MyClass(withTitle: "C", andSortValue: 42),
    MyClass(withTitle: "D", andSortValue: 1337),
    MyClass(withTitle: "E", andSortValue: 24)
])

arrayToSort
    .subscribe(onNext: { ar in
        for element in ar {
            print(element.title)
        }
    })
```

Actual result :

```
A //4
B //2
C //42 
D //1337 
E //24
```

Expected result :

```
B //2
A //4
E //24
C //42
D //1337
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
arrayToSort
    .flatMap { classes in
        Observable.combineLatest(
            classes.map { elem in
                elem.sortAttribute.map { (elem, $0) }
            }
        )
    }
    .map {
        $0.sorted(by: { a, b in a.1 < b.1 }).map { $0.0.title }
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    })
```

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of solution i was looking for ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arrayToSort
.subscribe(onNext: { ar in
        let sortedAr = ar.sorted(by: { $0.title < $1.title })
        for element in sortedAr {
            print(element.title)
        }
    })
```

**UPDATE:**
Set your sort attribute NOT Observable... Just Int

```
class MyClass {

    let title:String
    let sortAttribute: Int

    init(withTitle title:String, andSortValue sortValue: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.sortAttribute = sortValue
    }

}
```

and then:

```
arrayToSort
    .subscribe(onNext: { ar in
            let sortedAr = ar.sorted(by: { $0.sortAttribute < $1.sortAttribute })
            for element in sortedAr {
                print(element.title)
            }
        })
```

if you will keep it as Observable, you would have to subscribe to each sortAttribute extract its Int and then somehow sort it, it is waste of processing power for a simple sorting...

Comment: No, I don't want my array to be sorted by "title" attribute but by "sortAttribute". I edited my sample to be clearer.

Comment: "Set your sort attribute NOT Observable... Just Int" > I will not ask my question if it would be possible.

Comment: I cannot see what is the Benefit of having Observable<Int>?